# How do I get Rails to only show/allow new records when using fields_for when validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

I'm trying to let users add multiple payments at once via a custom URL but running into an issue of existing records if there are validation issues.

The URL "/setup/payments" pre-populates the form with 2 example payments to give them an idea of the type of payments they can add.

If there is a problem with validation, i.e. they forget to add a Value to one of the fields, the form adds any existing items in @company.payments which look like this in the rendered HTML:

```
<input id="company_payments_attributes_0_id" name="company[payments_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="104">
```

If the user tries to submit the form again it will run into validation issues on any of these because neither Name or Value are present for them in the form.

How can I make sure existing items in the @company.payments aren't added to this form if there are validation issues and I need to render the form again?

Here is a sample of all of the code I'm using:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get '/setup/payments', :to => 'companies#setup_payments', :as => :setup_payments
post '/setup/payments', :to => 'companies#save_payments', :as => :save_payments
```

**app/models/company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :payments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments

end
```

**app/models/payment.rb**

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :company
    validates :name, :presence => { :message => "Name is required" }
    validates :value, :presence => { :message => "Value is required" }

end
```

**app/controllers/companies_controller.rb**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

    def setup_payments

       @company = curent_user.company

       @payments = [
       {
          :name => 'Coffee',
          :value => 5
       },
       {
          :name => 'Breakfast',
          :value => 10
       }
       ]

       @company.payments.build(@payments)

    end

    def save_payments

       @company = curent_user.company

       if @company.update(company_params)

          redirect_to root_path and return

       else

          render :setup_payments

       end

    end

    private

    def company_params
       params.require(:company).permit(:name, payments_attributes: [:name, :value, :_destroy])
    end

end
```

**app/views/companies/setup_payments.html.erb**

```
<% if @company.errors.any? %>

   <h2>We found <%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %>:</h2>

   <ol>
      <% @company.errors.each do |attr, msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
   </ol>

<% end %>

<%= nested_form_for @company, :url => save_payments_path, :method => 'post' do |f| %>

   <% if params[:company].nil? %>

      <%= f.fields_for :payments, @company.payments.build(@payments) do |payment| %>

         <%= render :partial => 'payments', :locals => { :payment => payment } %>

      <% end %>

   <% else %>

      <%= f.fields_for :payments do |payment| %>

         <%= render :partial => 'payments', :locals => { :payment => payment } %>

      <% end %>

   <% end %>

   <%= f.link_to_add "Add Another", :payments %>

   <%= f.button "Save Payments" %>

<% end %>
```

**app/views/companies/_payments.html.erb**

```
<% if payment.object.new_record? %>

  <%= payment.text_field :name %>
  <%= payment.text_field :value %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore any nested payments where either the name or value is blank then you can use the recject_if option on accepts_nested_attributes_for.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? || attributes['value'].blank? }
```

So when you save an existing payment which doesn't have either the 'name' or 'value' attributes it will simply ignore them.

Another option would be to not display existing payments records within the app/views/companies/setup_payments.html.erb

**app/controllers/companies_controller.rb**

```
def setup_payments

   @company = curent_user.company

   @example_attributes = [
   {
      :name => 'Coffee',
      :value => 5
   },
   {
      :name => 'Breakfast',
      :value => 10
   }
   ]

   @payments = @company.payments.build(@example_attributes)

end
```

**app/views/companies/setup_payments.html.erb**

```
<% if params[:company].nil? %>

  <%= f.fields_for :payments, @company.payments.build(@example_attributes) do |payment| %>

     <%= render :partial => 'payments', :locals => { :payment => payment } %>

  <% end %>

<% else %>

  <%= f.fields_for :payments, @payments do |payment| %>

     <%= render :partial => 'payments', :locals => { :payment => payment } %>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simon, I ended up fixing the issue with the following code change:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

This way only the new items don't go through validation. If I tried to reject items if either the Name or Value where blank then I could run into a situation where a "new item" in the form doesn't go through validation because it had one of those empty. I wanted only new items to go through validation and not existing ones.

P.S. if it isn't already clear I'm quite new to Rails so if anyone has any thoughts on how I could do the above in a more "Railsy" way please do let me know :)